# FFmpegFrameRecorder Issue

Tags: java-native-interface, javacv

While using FFmpegFrameRecorder from JavaCV the JVM crashes with the following message :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000699d6a64, pid=4076, tid=308
#
# JRE version: 7.0_13-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [avformat-54.dll+0xd6a64]  av_read_play+0x4
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Sagar Jadhav\Documents\NetBeansWorkspace\OpenCV\hs_err_pid4076.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Java Result: 1
```

---

The code is as follows :

```
package com.opencv.windows;

import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;

public class VideoRecorderDemo
{
    OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber;
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;
    CanvasFrame canvasFrame;

    VideoRecorderDemo() 
    {
        grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("c:\\sample.mp4");
        recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("c:\\sample1.mp4", 2);
        canvasFrame = new CanvasFrame("Video Recorder Demo");      
        canvasFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try
        {
            grabber.start();

            opencv_core.IplImage image;
            while((canvasFrame.isVisible()) && (image = grabber.grab()) != null)
                canvasFrame.showImage(image);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        init();
        startRecording();
        stopRecording();
    }

    void init()
    {
        try
        {
            grabber.start();
            recorder.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void startRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            opencv_core.IplImage image;
            while((canvasFrame.isVisible()) && (image = grabber.grab()) != null)
            {   
                recorder.record(image);
                canvasFrame.showImage(image);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void stopRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            grabber.stop();
            recorder.stop();
            canvasFrame.dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new VideoRecorderDemo();
    }
}
```

I am using OpenCV 2.4.3 libs and the ffmpeg libs provided from zeronoe (ffmpeg-20130209-git-969039e-win64-shared)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

u must use this version of ffmpeg:

http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/ffmpeg-20121029-git-11d695d-win64-shared.7z

i had ur problem but i searched the JavaCV readme file and i found that JavaCV has been compiled with this version of ffmpeg

good luck